# Infinitely many real roots

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that, $\tan Z = aZ$ where $a>0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ has infinitely many roots.

I know how to solve if $Z \in \mathbb{R}$. I will draw the graphs and will find where the graphs cut.
But how to solve them in complex ?
Will anybody please help?

Comment: If you know that there are infinitely many real solutions, what stops you from concluding that there are infinitely many complex solutions?

Comment: You cant evaluate the zeros without the use of approximations. I think you just must prove that they are infinite solutions.